# Error when trying to create a serviceaccount key in deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-deployment-manager

**The error is below:**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1544517871651-57cbb1716c8b8-4fa66ff2-9980028f]: errors:
- code: MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD
  location: /deployments/infrastructure/resources/projects/resources-practice/serviceAccounts/storage-buckets-backend/keys/json->$.properties->$.parent
  message: |-
    Missing required field 'parent' with schema:
    {
      "type" : "string"
    }
```

**Below is my jinja template content:**

```
resource:
- name: {{ name }}-keys
    type: iam.v1.serviceAccounts.key
    properties:
      name: projects/{{ properties["projectID"] }}/serviceAccounts/{{ serviceAccount["name"] }}/keys/json
      privateKeyType: enum(TYPE_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE)
      keyAlgorithm: enum(KEY_ALG_RSA_2048)
```

**P.S.
My reference for the properties is based on https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys**

Comment: I can only help with part of the solution. 1) You are missing parent. This needs to be an existing service account: `parent: projects/development-123456/serviceAccounts/mysa@development-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: 2) Remove the enum wrapping the privateKeyType and keyAlgoritm.

Comment: @JohnHanley, can you give me an example of 1.)

Comment: Do you mean an example existing service account?

Comment: The deployment that you are trying to do, creates service account credentials for an existing service account in your project. The problem is that I don't know how to tell Deployment Manager to save the returned credentials to a file.

Comment: Excuse my asking for an example, ley me try your suggestions first

Comment: 3) Remove the name under properties. It is not used (I think).

Comment: I just added the parent property `parent: projects/{{ project }}/serviceAccounts/$(ref.{{ name }}.email)` and it worked. 

Now the question is, how to retrieve the downloadable json-file key?

Comment: If you figure out the download part please let me know.

Comment: You can use the output like in this reference https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/expose-information-outputs.. In my case I used the `publicKeyData` property then have it `base64decoded`

Answer (score 2):

I will post the response of @John as the answer for the benefit of the community.

The parent was missing, needing an existing [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/create):

```
projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT}
```

where ACCOUNT value can be the email or the uniqueID of the service account.

Regarding the template, please remove the enum wrapping the privateKeyType and keyAlgoritm.

The above deployment creates a service account credentials for an existing service account, and in order to retrieve this downloadable json key file, it can be exposed using [outputs](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/expose-information-outputs) using the publicKeyData property then have it base64decoded.

Comment: Dany, can you modify your answer to include the final solution. This will help others to see the solution more clearly.

Comment: But why is that `parent` not in the documentation?

Comment: Actually I could not find any documentation for creating Service Accounts with Deployment Manager or any examples. That is why I did some research to help you as I wanted to know too. All I could find is the REST API, which does not translate very well to Deployment Manager YAML. The REST API is not a reference for Deployment Manager (they are quite different in elements in many cases).